# How to copy bash script to docker-entrypoint.sh in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker

I have a custom bash script that I want to copy to docker-entrypoint.sh in my Dockfile.

**My docker file**

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:latest as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN /entrypoint.sh >> docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**My entrypoint.sh file**

```
#!/bin/sh
JSON_STRING='window.configs = { \
  "GLOBAL_VAR":"'"${GLOBAL_VAR}"'", \
}'
sed -i "s@// CONFIGURATIONS_PLACEHOLDER@${JSON_STRING}@" /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
exec "$@"
```

**How can I copy the custom entrypoint.sh to docker-entrypoint.sh ?**

Comment: what do you mean by "How can I copy the custom entrypoint.sh to docker-entrypoint.sh"? What are you _actually_ trying to do here?

Comment: I am following this article to use environment variables in my vue app via docker-compose https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-js-runtime-environment-variables-807fa8f68665
But my nginx conf template file is not being copied in docker-compose file.

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis What or where is your "nginx conf template file"? How does it relate to your `entrypoint.sh`? Please don't make it necessary for us to read an article just to understand your task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All .sh files that located in `/docker-entrypoint.d` folder executes when nginx container starts.
You can put your .sh file into `/docker-entrypoint.d` folder and set him +x permission instead adding line into docker-entrypoint.sh file.

```
COPY YOUR_SCRIPT.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.d/YOUR_SCRIPT.sh
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks