# How to rename a file in docker image during docker run command?

Tags: docker

I want to rename a conf.dev.json file to conf.json within the image during docker run time.  How is this accomplished?

I don't want to rename the file during image build because I don't want to build env specific images and mounting a volume wont really work because I'm serving the file from within nginx server running in the container which is serving the site from the container image's /html directory.

Comment: What have you already tried?  Do you have a [mcve]?  The two easiest things I can think of are either bind-mounting the specific file, renaming it; or using an entrypoint wrapper script to rename it on startup.  Using an environment variable to point your application to the correct file also might help.

Answer (score 0):

ok it looks like with nginx there is a magic folder that contains scripts to execute when the images starts.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575191/491436

I'm going to try this but if there is a more elegant way to approach this please do let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file `config.dev.json` is located in `/local` on your host and the target file inside the container should be located in `/tmp/config.json`, then

```
docker run -v /local/config.dev.json:/tmp/config.json -it -p 8080:8080 yourimage
```